# Nodejs Date Parsing Inconsistency

Tags: node.js, date, parsing

Node seems to parse dates differently depending on whether the month has a leading zero or not. Specifically, it seems to use a different time zone.
Here is an example, Node v19.3.0

```
console.log(new Date('2021-01-25').toISOString());
// Output: 2021-01-25T00:00:00.000Z

console.log(new Date('2021-1-25').toISOString());
// Output: 2021-01-24T22:00:00.000Z
```

What's going on here? Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#date_string.

`2021-01-25` is a date in ISO format and `new Date('...')` parses this as `00:00:00` on that date in UTC.

`2021-1-25` or `2021/1/25` or `1/25/2021` or even `Jan 25 2021` are non-ISO representations of a date. Parsing them depends on the language with which Node.js is installed, because the month name (`Jan`) is language-specific. Parsing such dates is handled differently and leads to `00:00:00` on that date in the operating system time zone. In your case this leads to `2021-01-25T00:00:00+02:00`, which is concurrent with `2021-01-24T22:00:00Z`.